# How would I animate an auto-updating mysql query result?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, parsing

Basically, how would I make an auto-updating mysql query result animated using jquery? I would want it to look like a newsfeed that is animated and slides down when a result it added? How difficuilt would this be to achieve and what would I use to do it?

Thanks,

Cameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need some JS, PHP and HTML skill.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function create_ajax()
{
    try
    {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) 
        {
            try
            {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e)
            {
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return ajaxRequest;
}
```

You need this function in your HTML file, to start the message service:

```
function StartUp()
{
    /** Jquery **/
    setTimeout(function() {$('#message').fadeOut('fast');}, 5000);
    UserLogService();
}
```

This function helps to connect to PHP:

```
function MessageService()
{
    setTimeout('MessageService()', 60000);

    var ajaxRequest;
    ajaxRequest=create_ajax();

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = 
    function()
    {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            message = ajaxRequest.responseText.split(';');

            if (message[0])
            {
                headMessageDisplay(message[0], message[1]);
                setTimeout('headMessageNoDisplay()', 30000);
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "xxx.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

In your PHP get the messages:

```
if ($msg)
{
    $this->Show($msg);
    exit();
}
```

**PHP:** This shows the message from PHP:

```
private function Show($msg = null)
{

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($msg); $i++)
    {
        $error = $this->html;

        $error = str_replace('{MESSAGE}',  $msg[$i], $error);
        $error = str_replace('{TYPE}', error, $error);
        $error = str_replace('{DISPLAY}', 'block', $error);

        $this->message .= $error;
    }

    print $this->message;
}
```

This makes the message itself:

```
        $r = $_REQUEST["sql"]->Query("SELECT m.id, m.message, t.name as type FROM db_table_message  m JOIN db_table_messagetype t ON (t.id = m.type) WHERE m.processing = '0' AND m.user_id = '".$_REQUEST["user"]->Id."' 
                                        AND m.date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND m.date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MINUTE) LIMIT 1");
        $a = $_REQUEST["sql"]->GetRecord($r, 0);

        if (!$a["id"])
        {
            $r = $_REQUEST["sql"]->Query("SELECT m.id, m.message, t.name as type FROM db_table_message m JOIN db_table_messagetype t ON (t.id = m.type) WHERE date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND m.processing = '0' AND m.user_id = '".$_REQUEST["user"]->Id."' LIMIT 1");
            $a = $_REQUEST["sql"]->GetRecord($r, 0);
        }

        if ($a["id"])
        {
             $_REQUEST["sql"]->Query("UPDATE db_table_message SET processing = '1' WHERE id = '$a[id]'");
        }
        else
        {
            $r = $_REQUEST["sql"]->Query("SELECT m.id, m.message, t.name as type FROM db_table_message m JOIN db_table_messagetype t ON (t.id = m.type) WHERE m.user_id = '0' LIMIT 1");
            $a = $_REQUEST["sql"]->GetRecord($r, 0);
        }

        $this->Show($a["message"], $a["type"]);
    }

    private function Show($message = null, $type = null)
    {
        if ((!$message) || (!$type)) return false;

        switch($type)
        {
            case "information":
                $type = information;
            break;

            case "warning":
                $type = warning;
            break;

            case "error":
                $type = error;
            break;
        }

        print "$message;$type";
```

Use a PHP Class to get the message from the database... There are many things needed to do this. I nearly forgot to get the old messages from the database on page load by php.

Then, if everything works, add:

**ANIMATION**

```
$("selector").fadeIn(slow);
```

If you want to do the animation with jQuery. :) The animation itself is the last thing you have to worry about. :)

Answer (score 1):

Broadly:

- Create a PHP page that returns the results of the MySQL query.
- Periodically `load()` that page with Javascript from the containing page.
- Update the contents of the containing element if a difference is found.

Here's a very brief outline. Initially, let's get the results.

```
// results.php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl` LIMIT 10 ORDER BY date_created DESC";

if(!$query = mysql_query($sql))
  trigger_error(mysql_error());

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   print_r($result);
```

Then make a page to show them.

```
// index.html

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadResults() {
  $('#results').fadeTo('fast' , 0).load('results.php').fadeTo('fast' , 1);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   loadResults();
   var interval = self.setInterval(loadResults(), 10000);

});

</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Untested.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my oar in here although this is a similar solution to Dae except using jQuery templates and JSON.  I don't work with php myself but creating JSON doesn't seem too difficult with json_encode()

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/WXgrM/)